# yum clean all gives multiple string errors

Tags: rhel, redhat-satellite, spacewalk

When I am trying to connect instance to Satellite Server it's failing. I tried to perform basic system updates and tried running yum clean all. However, I am getting following lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 300, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 115, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 229, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 911, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 363, in _getConfig
    self.plugins.run('init')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 184, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/share/yum-plugins/ulninfo.py", line 23, in init_hook
    login_info = up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 219, in getLoginInfo
    login(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 167, in login
    if readCachedLogin():
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 133, in readCachedLogin
    expireTime = float(li['X-RHN-Auth-Expiration'])
KeyError: 'X-RHN-Auth-Expiration'
```

Can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: What version of rhn-client-tools package are you using? I cannot find the code from the traceback in any released version. What version of Satellite you are using Satellite 5.x or 6.x? Those are completely different. I assume you are using Satellite 5.x. Did you register your machine first using rhn_register command?

Answer (score 0):

Check your subscription status, it may be causing this error. Though, honestly, I don't know why it would with a 'clean all'. That "KeyError" at the end is what raises my curiosity.

```
subscription-manager status
subscription-manager list
```

Comment: It not only does with clean all. In fact, with all yum commands like : yum update repo ; yum repo list. When I run : subscription-manager status I am getting -bash: subscription-manager: command not found

Comment: Are you using yum as root or using sudo?

If you are using RHEL, then as root or using sudo:
`yum install subscription-manager`

Though you may need to get the rpm for subscription-manager from the ISO image if your yum is broken.  This is also assuming that you _are_ using RHEL _and_ need it licensed/registered.

Comment: You can also try `up2date` and `satellite-sync`that may fix things (or get them closer)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple fix for that. I figured out running the `rhnreg` command at the same time on multiple servers to register client on spacewalk/redhat satellite cause this issue. For example, I run this command on 4 of my servers and only     one server got registered successfully.

3 of my servers are throwing the same error mentioned above. Here is what I did to resolve the issue.

Took a backup of my current `up2dateAuth.py` file

```
 cp /usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py /usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py_`date +%m_%d_%Y`
```

I did `scp` from the first server which is successfully registered with spacewalk server.

```
 scp /usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py root@server2:/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/
 ls -lrth /usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py*
```

run

```
 yum repolist

 rhnreg_ks --sslCACert=/usr/share/rhn/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT --serverUrl=https://myspacewalkserver-corp.com/XMLRPC  --activationkey=1-oraclelinux6-x86_64 --force

 yum repolist (it work like a charm)
```

**P.S. don't forget to remove cd /etc/yum.repos.d/; rm -rf spacewalk26-client.repo before running the rhnreg command or else it will throw another error.**

Disable access to the Spacewalk Client repository in the Oracle Linux Yum Server repository configuration file or delete /etc/yum.repos.d/spacewalk26-client.repo.